# Approximation of a sum

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, approximation, factorial

I would like to approximate (or calculate) the below sum.

$$
\frac {1} {{2 N \choose M}} \, \sum_{k = 1}^{N / 2} \frac {2^{2 k}} {2 k} \, {N \choose 2 k} \, {N - 2 k \choose \frac {M - 2 k} {2}}
$$

Do you know any methods I could use? Thanks

Comment: Maybe treat this as a Monte Carlo integration exercise

Comment: You could start with "simplifying" - get read of some values.